# General function definite integration result in probability understanding (CDF)

Tags: probability

The following result is quoted in the probability book:

$$\frac{d}{da} \int_{-\infty}^af(x)dx =f(a)$$

I think this is trivial, but I can't see how they arrived at it, the only similar expressions I came across previously were of the form:

$$\int \frac{d}{dx} \sin x \ dx = \sin x$$

So the one immediately above is indefinite and the function is exact, not general. Can you help me to understand how to arrive at the first expression? Thank you

Comment: This is the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: $\frac{d}{da} \int_{-\infty}^af(x)dx =\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{a + h}f(x)dx - \int_{-\infty}^af(x)dx}{h}= \lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\int_{a}^{a + h}f(x)dx}{h}= f(a) \times  \lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\int_{a}^{a + h}dx}{h} = f(a)$. All this provided the definite integral exists in the first place.

Comment: @vnd The step when you factor $f(a)$ being problematic, of course, and requiring either hypotheses on $f$ or some weakening of the conclusion.

Comment: @Did. Indeed. It's just a rough justification though, otherwise one could refer to the standard proof.